# $ionicHistory.goBack() not working correctly with ion tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

My page contains 3 tabs, if i forward to next page from tab3 and then coming back from that page using $ionicHistory.goBack() it redirects to tab1. how to make it redirects to tab3 itself

```
function sample($scope,$ionicHistory){
            $ionicHistory.goBack();
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to do that just through $state.  I'm new to Ionic myself as I had my first peek back in December (2016).  However, I happened to have this exact scenario.  This is how I solved it.

In my case, I was not using tabs.  Instead, I had three different DIVs that were visible depending on the "tab number". When initializing the view, I set it to "1" and used the property to control what code is executed.

I'm guessing that the control you're using has a property like that to identify and set the particular tab you need, as this is the most likely way to change tabs on tab-click.  Consider putting the value of that property "tab #" into the appropriate service used by the controller.  This is a stripped-down version of actual code in one of my services defined via Factory.

YourService.js:

```
    // controllers are instances.  When navigating away, state is lost. This
    // tracks the tab we wish to view when we load the home page.
    var activeHomePageTab = 1;

    var service = {
        getActiveTab: getActiveTab,
        setActiveTab: setActiveTab,
        ...
     };

    return service;

    ////////////////

    function getActiveTab() { return activeHomePageTab; }
    function setActiveTab(num) { activeHomePageTab = num; }
    ...
```

Here, the functions are private.  In your controller, when you set your tab, also set this property.  As a singleton, this will remain in effect as long as your application is running.

Next, in your init() routine, when the controller is loaded, check for this property and set the tab if it is defined:

```
function init() {
    var tab = YourService.getActiveTab();
    if (tab !== undefined) {
        setTab(tab);
    } else {
        setTab(1)
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, there are other ways - maybe using Value or a property on a Constant object.